# Generar un objeto mediante un metodo. variable might not have been initialized

Tags: java, objeto

No he sabido muy bien cómo titular la pregunta, y por la misma razón no sé muy bien cómo plantearla de forma más sencilla, pero ahí voy...

Tengo un proyecto de gestión bancaria. En él, tengo las clases **Principal** (donde está el main), **Persona** (donde creo titulares de cuentas y personas autorizadas), **CuentaBancaria** y **Banco**.

En el ejercicio se me pide que cree una clase **Banco** con un método **void datosInicio()** que se encargue de crear unas cuantas cuentas bancarias para poder "jugar" con la aplicación.

Mi problema es que no sé cómo llamar al método desde **Principal** para crear el objecto **Banco** inicial.

```
public class Banco {
    private String nombre;
    private HashMap<String, CuentaBancaria> cuentas = new HashMap<>();
    
    public Banco(String nombreBanco, HashMap cuentas){
        this.nombre = nombreBanco;
        this.cuentas = cuentas;
    }
    
    public void datosInicio(){
        Persona t1 = new Persona("11223344A", "Gracia Macías");
        Persona t2 = new Persona("22334455B", "Armando Líos");
        Persona t3 = new Persona("33445566C", "Dolores Fuertes");
        Persona t4 = new Persona("44556677D", "Lindo Gatito");
        Persona t5 = new Persona("55667788E", "Gloria Bendita");
                
        CuentaBancaria c1 = new CuentaBancaria(1001, t1);
        CuentaBancaria c2 = new CuentaBancaria(1002, t2);
        CuentaBancaria c3 = new CuentaBancaria(1003, t3);
        CuentaBancaria c4 = new CuentaBancaria(1004, t4);
        CuentaBancaria c5 = new CuentaBancaria(1005, t5);
        
        c1.ingresar(250);
        c2.ingresar(500);
        c3.ingresar(750);
        c4.ingresar(1000);
        c5.ingresar(1250);
                
        cuentas.put("1001", c1);
        cuentas.put("1002", c2);
        cuentas.put("1003", c3);
        cuentas.put("1004", c4);
        cuentas.put("1005", c5);
        
        Banco miBanco = new Banco("Banca Ética DAM", cuentas);
    }
  }
```

En la clase **Principal**, y aquí es donde no me aclaro, trato de crear el objeto Banco que necesito dentro del método main()

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Banco miBanco;
    miBanco.datosInicio();
}
```

Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda, incluida aquella a cambiar el titulo de mi pregunta para que pueda ayudar al siguiente que venga con un problema parecido.

P.D. El error que obtengo es...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - variable miBanco might not have been initialized
    at a_basico.Principal.main(Principal.java:23)
C:\Users\jakob\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\jakob\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Y la linea 23 de la que habla es

```
miBanco.datosInicio();
```

Comment: Y, ¿cuál es el problema o error?

Comment: En el `main` tienes que inicializar el objeto, por ejemplo: `Banco miBanco= new Banco();` Otra cosa incompatible que veo es que al declarar el método `datosInicio()` del tipo `void` (¿requerimiento del ejercicio?)  no podrás retornar desde él el objeto `Banco` con la información cargada. Es un poco raro como requerimiento. A lo sumo, la clase tendría que tener un *getter*  que te devuelva el objeto con los datos que le pongas en `datosInicio()` o algo así.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si, el ejercicio me dice explícitamente que ha de ser de tipo void. Si pudiera devolver un objeto de tipo Banco me hubiera resultado más sencillo, pero vaya...tengo que hacerlo así. Por otro lado, he probado a inicializar el objeto banco tanto asi **Banco miBanco = new Banco();** como así **Banco miBanco = new Banco(String, HashMap);** pero en la primera me dice que necesita argumentos y en la segunda me dice "Uncompilable source code - Erroneous ctor sym type: <any>"

Comment: Sí es que hay que adaptar la clase al requerimiento del ejercicio, dotándola de otros constructores. Ahora te escribo una respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes cambiar el constructor de Banco, y eliminar el argumento `cuentas` para que sea así:

```
public Banco(String nombreBanco){
    this.nombre = nombreBanco;
}
```

Luego, en el método datosInicio() eliminas la línea `Banco miBanco = new Banco("Banca Ética DAM", cuentas);`:

```
public void datosInicio(){
    // ...
    this.cuentas.put("1001", c1);
    this.cuentas.put("1002", c2);
    this.cuentas.put("1003", c3);
    this.cuentas.put("1004", c4);
    this.cuentas.put("1005", c5);
    // Banco miBanco = new Banco("Banca Ética DAM", cuentas);
}
```

Finalmente en el main sólo tendrías que crear el objeto Banco y llamar al método.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Banco miBanco = new Banco("Banca Ética DAM"); // Banco, pero sin cuentas
    miBanco.datosInicio(); // Ahora el banco tiene cuentas
    // miBanco.getCuentas();
}
```

Como nota aparte, puedes crear el método getCuentas() para obtener las cuentas del Banco.

```
public HashMap<String, CuentaBancaria> getCuentas() {
    return this.cuentas;
}
```

Comment: No sabía que se podía hacer eso: crear dos constructores diferentes, y gracias a tu respuesta parece que está solucionado. Lo mismo con la respuesta de @A.Cedano

Comment: Me alegra que te haya funcionado! Si quieres más información acerca de la sobrecarga de métodos, puedes leer [este artículo](https://javadesdecero.es/poo/sobrecarga-de-metodos/).

Answer (score 1):

Estas inicializando nuevamente `Banco` al llamar `datosInicio()` lo cual no es correcto, te sugiero realizar lo siguiente, al llamar a tu método `datosInicio()` para inicializar los datos, asigna las cuentas al objeto:

```
public class Banco {
    private String nombre;
    private HashMap<String, CuentaBancaria> cuentas = new HashMap<>();

    public Banco(String nombreBanco, HashMap cuentas){
        this.nombre = nombreBanco;
        this.cuentas = cuentas;
    }

    public void datosInicio(){
        Persona t1 = new Persona("11223344A", "Gracia Macías");
        Persona t2 = new Persona("22334455B", "Armando Líos");
        Persona t3 = new Persona("33445566C", "Dolores Fuertes");
        Persona t4 = new Persona("44556677D", "Lindo Gatito");
        Persona t5 = new Persona("55667788E", "Gloria Bendita");

        CuentaBancaria c1 = new CuentaBancaria(1001, t1);
        CuentaBancaria c2 = new CuentaBancaria(1002, t2);
        CuentaBancaria c3 = new CuentaBancaria(1003, t3);
        CuentaBancaria c4 = new CuentaBancaria(1004, t4);
        CuentaBancaria c5 = new CuentaBancaria(1005, t5);

        c1.ingresar(250);
        c2.ingresar(500);
        c3.ingresar(750);
        c4.ingresar(1000);
        c5.ingresar(1250);

        cuentas.put("1001", c1);
        cuentas.put("1002", c2);
        cuentas.put("1003", c3);
        cuentas.put("1004", c4);
        cuentas.put("1005", c5);

        //Banco miBanco = new Banco("Banca Ética DAM", cuentas);
       //Asigna cuentas a objeto Banco
        this.cuentas = cuentas;


    }
  }
```

Ahora para inicializar correctamente tu objeto `Banco`, crea un `HashMap` en el cual se llenarán los datos de la cuenta e inicializa tu objeto, posteriormente llama `datosInicio()` y tu objeto tendrá todos los datos de la cuenta:

```
 HashMap cuentas = new HashMap();
 Banco miBanco = new Banco("Banca Ética DAM", cuentas);
 miBanco.datosInicio();
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenga en cuenta que el objeto `miBanco` esta siendo declarado mas nunca creado como tal.
Este debe ser creado con la sintaxis

```
miBanco = new Banco();
```

Si no envia parametros al constructor, en la clase Banco debe haber un constructor que no reciba parametros y que inicialice los objetos o variables propios de este. Asi:

```
public Banco(){
        this.nombre = "Banco X";
        this.cuentas = cuentas; // Ya que este ha sido creado con la clase Banco
}
```

Ya despues de credo el objeto, si deberia poder acceder al metodo de

```
miBanco.datosInicio();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

La contradicción es que creas la instancia del objeto desde `datosInicio()`, pero al ser del tipo `void` luego no puedes devolver esa instancia, se queda atrapada ahí dentro.

Podrías crear un constructor en la clase `Banco` que admita sólo el nombre, para casos en los que se sepa sólo ese dato al momento de crear el objeto, como es este ejercicio, porque los otros elementos se crean desde dentro de la misma clase. Esto se llama *constructores múltiples* y es una práctica habitual en Java.

```
public class Banco {
    private String nombre;
    private HashMap<String, CuentaBancaria> cuentas = new HashMap<>();

    //Constructor sólo con el nombre
    public Banco(String nombreBanco){
        this.nombre = nombreBanco;
    }
    public Banco(String nombreBanco, HashMap cuentas){
        this.nombre = nombreBanco;
        this.cuentas = cuentas;
    }


    public void datosInicio(){
        Persona t1 = new Persona("11223344A", "Gracia Macías");
        Persona t2 = new Persona("22334455B", "Armando Líos");
        Persona t3 = new Persona("33445566C", "Dolores Fuertes");
        Persona t4 = new Persona("44556677D", "Lindo Gatito");
        Persona t5 = new Persona("55667788E", "Gloria Bendita");

        CuentaBancaria c1 = new CuentaBancaria(1001, t1);
        CuentaBancaria c2 = new CuentaBancaria(1002, t2);
        CuentaBancaria c3 = new CuentaBancaria(1003, t3);
        CuentaBancaria c4 = new CuentaBancaria(1004, t4);
        CuentaBancaria c5 = new CuentaBancaria(1005, t5);

        c1.ingresar(250);
        c2.ingresar(500);
        c3.ingresar(750);
        c4.ingresar(1000);
        c5.ingresar(1250);

        cuentas.put("1001", c1);
        cuentas.put("1002", c2);
        cuentas.put("1003", c3);
        cuentas.put("1004", c4);
        cuentas.put("1005", c5);
    }
  }
```

Luego, desde el `main` creas el objeto usando ese constructor y pasándole el nombre del banco.

Si el requerimiento es otro, dado que se trata de un ejercicio, puedes dejarlo como lo tienes, pero debes crear un constructor vacío, crear la instancia desde el `main` con `new Banco()` y en `datosInicio()` setear también el nombre como haces con las cuentas:  `this.nombre="Banca Ética DAM";`

Aquí instanciamos el objeto pasándole el nombre del banco:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Banco miBanco = new Banco ("Banca Ética DAM");
    miBanco.datosInicio();
}
```

Así debería funcionar.

Comment: No sabía que se podía hacer eso: crear dos constructores diferentes, y gracias a tu respuesta parece que está solucionado. Lo mismo con la respuesta de @JCAguilera.

Comment: @Calfa sí, en Java puedes dotar a una clase de múltiples constructores, esto se suele hacer cuando se requiere crear instancias de esa clase desde contextos distintos. Según la cantidad de parámetros que pases al crear el objeto Java llamará al constructor adecuado. Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Como una de las respuestas te comento, lo único que estas ejecutando en la función principal de tu programa es la declaración de la variable, sin la correspondiente asignación de esta misma (Que entiendo que es tu intención y problema).

En Java la manera de retornar una nueva instancia de una clase, es mediante el uso de la sintaxis:

```
new Class(params)
```

Substituyendo "Class" por el nombre de la clase que se desea instanciar, y siendo params una o más variables (totalmente opcionales) del constructor de dicha clase de manera que te quedaría algo así:

```
Banco miBanco = new Banco("Nombre Banco", hashMapDeCuentas)
// "Nombre Banco" es un Objeto String y hashMapDeCuentas un Objeto HashMap
```

Intuyo que estas siguiendo algún curso que requiere conocimiento previo de [Programación Orientada a Objetos](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/oops-object-oriented-design/).

Observando un poco mejor tu caso, veo que deseas crear una única instancia de Banco, además, por tu intento de crear dicha instancia desde la misma clase me hace pensar que estas basándote en un patrón de diseño de software llamado 
[Singleton](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-class-java/)

Donde la solución a tu problema sería eliminar los parámetros de tu constructor y añadir el siguiente código a tu clase Banco:

```
private static final Banco INSTANCE = new Banco();
public static Banco getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}
```

De manera que en tu clase principal puedes simplemente hacer esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Banco miBanco = miBanco.getInstance();
    miBanco.datosInicio();
}
```

Cualquiera de las dos soluciones es válida!

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta. La razón por la que no seguiré tu consejo es exclusivamente porque implicaría copiar y pegar algo que no entiendo en absoluto. Aún así, muchísimas gracias por haberte molestado en ayudarme.

Comment: @Calfa comenta lo que no entiendes para poder ayudarte :)